# Implementing Tree Structure In MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

this question may asked by several people.But still I didn't get a right answer. So here it is

I want to load Continents, Countries and Cities to below combo boxes. So I need to make relation between those. Means city need be in a country and country belongs to a continent. So of course I am talking about a tree structure. So how should I implement this in MYSQL database in efficient way? How many tables need? How to do the relation among those?

Here is the image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/st4oz.jpg

Comment: It's not as easy as it seems, if one wants to do it completely right. There are some countries which belong to two continents at least, i.e. Turkey and Russia.

Comment: @VMai There's always a party breaker :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are formal ways to represent arbitrary trees, but I think the following is simpler and should be sufficient:

```
CREATE TABLE Continents (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE (name)
)

CREATE TABLE Countries (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    continent INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (continent) REFERENCES Continents(id),
    UNIQUE (name)
)

CREATE TABLE Cities (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    country INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (country) REFERENCES Countries(id),
    UNIQUE (name)
)
```

I didn't test the code, so there may be some syntax errors. I hope the intent is clear, though.

@Vmai raises an excellent point in his comment on the question.
My solution would be to have the "problem countries" once in the Countries table for every continent they are in. (So Turkey would be twice in the database, once with `continent` set to the `id` of Asia, and once to the `id` of Europe. Same for Russia.) The same goes for cities, of course.

Comment: Thank you. but what you mean by "There are formal ways to represent arbitrary trees"? Why is there any efficient method?

Comment: What about i.e. Omsk (Russia) and Moscow (Russia) :-) And what about [Istanbul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Istanbul)?

Comment: I mean there are ways to convert an arbitrarily deep tree to a database table, but I think those are unnecessarily complex for your case. Spltting the tree into multiple tables is IMHO much easier to read/comprehend, when you know the depth of the tree beforehand (and it makes sense to split the data - which I think it does, because a country is not a city is not a continent). @VMai

Comment: @VMai I answered your comments in reverse order by the way. I hope I didn't confuse you.

Comment: @VMai one formal way is as Hex494D49 suggests, another is `Modified Preorder Tree Traversal`. With formal I mean these ways have been mathematically proven and researched.

Comment: @11684 No problem. I'm playing the role of devils advocate here. I want to remind some border cases. This may be unnecessary here.

Comment: I am grateful for that! I would never have thought of these places with multiple 'parents' (in tree terminology). I hated topography (the subject in school). @VMai

Comment: @VMai I tried `Modified preorder tree traversal` and left it after couple of months. `Select` is fast but `inset/update` is performance killing :) I'm talking about millions of data so I'm back to `parent/child` structure.

Comment: @hex494D49 Indeed, parent/child is better for trees that have to be modified very often (but selection is a nightmare), modified preorder tree traversal is best for selection, but modification is a nightmare.

Comment: @VMai I added it to my answer, and I'll explain it in a couple of minutes. Who knows, maybe someone would like it :)

Answer (score 2):

All you need is **one table**. As long as the structure of data is the same, there's no reason to have three tables. And this way, you don't care about the depth and how the locations administratively are organized.

```
+-------------------------+
| locations               |
+-------------------------+
| location_id   (int)     | primary key
| location_name (varchar) |
| parent_id     (int)     | index   
+-------------------------+
```

Or another solution

```
+-------------------------+
| locations               |
+-------------------------+
| location_id   (int)     | primary key
| location_name (varchar) |
| left          (int)     |
| right         (int)     |       
+-------------------------+
```

To be explained...

Comment: This model (maybe in combination with a closure table for easy access to complete paths) is more flexible. I. e. North America -> US -> California -> Los Angeles (there may be subdivisions between California and Los Angeles too ...) vs. Europe -> Luxembourg -> Luxembourg. But on a minor scale and for a special use case I've had implemented the solution of @11684 The root object was a federal state and the border cases appeared later. I didn't forgot them.